# Parse Chunk of String Data into Tabular Data set using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am getting a chunk of string data from a User Interface from a .NET Web Application. The .NET developer wants to call a user defined stored procedure that needs to parse the string data into a tabular format.

**The sample String data is as follows:**

```
[EMPDetailsEntity(id=1, FName=ABC, Active=YES, LName=CCC, Created=Mon Jun 07 20:00:00 EDT 2021, UpdatedBy = null)
,EMPDetailsEntity(id=2, FName=DEF, Active=YES, LName=F'FF, Created=Sun Jun 13 20:00:00 EDT 2021, UpdatedBy = null)
,EMPDetailsEntity(id=3, FName=GH,I, Active=YES, LName=III, Created=Wed Jun 16 20:20:20 EDT 2021, UpdatedBy = null)
,EMPDetailsEntity(id=4, FName=JKL, Active=YES, LName=LL',L, Created=Wed Jun 16 20:20:20 EDT 2021, UpdatedBy = null)]
```

**I want to produce the above string data into tabular format. As given below:**

```
ID  FirstName  LastName  Active  CreatedDT   UpdatedBy
1     ABC        CCC       YES     06/07/2021  Null
2     DEF        FFF       YES     06/13/2021  Null
3     GHI        III       YES     06/16/2021  Null
4     JKL        LLL       YES     06/16/2021  Null
```

Please can anybody help me how to parse the string data into tabular format so that I can directly push the data into a SQL table.

Comment: Tell the UI developer to send you the data in XML (any version) or JSON (SQL 2016+).

Comment: Can we confirm that there will be no commas in any values? If so, we can parse this into comma separated values.

Comment: There can be commas in future for any value that is passed in the string.

Comment: If there can be commas you would be better to include an example in your test data.

Comment: Interesting that `LName=LL',L` as input becomes `LLL` as output. Similarly with `FName=GH,I` to `GHI`. What rule(s) apply? If you can't write the rules you can't write the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of a table-valued function in concert with a conditional aggregation

**Example or [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=b5dd039a1efa5df1b94ebbdc32413b32)**

```
Declare @S varchar(max) = '
[EMPDetailsEntity(id=1, FName=ABC, Active=YES, LName=CCC, Created=Mon Jun 07 20:00:00 EDT 2021, UpdatedBy = null)
,EMPDetailsEntity(id=2, FName=DEF, Active=YES, LName=F''FF, Created=Sun Jun 13 20:00:00 EDT 2021, UpdatedBy = null)
,EMPDetailsEntity(id=3, FName=GH,I, Active=YES, LName=III, Created=Wed Jun 16 20:20:20 EDT 2021, UpdatedBy = null)
,EMPDetailsEntity(id=4, FName=JKL, Active=YES, LName=LL'',L, Created=Wed Jun 16 20:20:20 EDT 2021, UpdatedBy = null)]
'

Select ID        = max(case when Item='id'        then value end)
      ,FirstName = max(case when Item='FName'     then value end)
      ,LastName  = max(case when Item='LName'     then value end)
      ,Active    = max(case when Item='Active'    then value end)
      ,CreateDt  = try_convert(date,stuff(stuff(max(case when Item='Created' then value end),11,13,''),1,4,''))
      ,UpdatedBy = case when max(case when Item='UpdatedBy' then value end) like '%null%' then null else max(case when Item='UpdatedBy' then value end) end
 From (
        Select Grp   = A.RetSeq
              ,Item  = left(B.RetVal,charindex('=',B.RetVal+'=')-1)
              ,Value = stuff(B.RetVal,1,charindex('=',B.RetVal+'='),'')
         From  [dbo].[tvf-Str-Parse](replace(replace(replace(replace(@S,'EMPDetailsEntity',''),')',''),']',''),'[',''),'(')  A
         Cross Apply [dbo].[tvf-Str-Parse](A.RetVal,', ') B
         Where len(A.RetVal)>25
      ) src
 Group By Grp
```

**Results**

[image]

**The Function if Interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[tvf-Str-Parse] (@String varchar(max),@Delimiter varchar(10))
Returns Table 
As
Return (  
    Select RetSeq = row_number() over (order by 1/0)
          ,RetVal = ltrim(rtrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
    From  ( values (cast('<x>' + replace((Select replace(@String,@Delimiter,'§§Split§§') as [*] For XML Path('')),'§§Split§§','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.'))) as A(x)
    Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
);
--Usage: Select * from [dbo].[tvf-Str-Parse]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
```

Comment: Really amazing. Thanks #John.!
It really worked great.  But one small question if i have to remove the comma/single quote from the values.  Can we do in the same query or do we use a function please to replace the commas or any other special characters.

Comment: @desi That would be a small tweak.   for example, in the final select  ... ,LastName  = replace(replace(max(case when Item='LName'     then value end),',',''),'''','') ...

Comment: @desi  Doing it in CROSS APPLY B would be risky.

Comment: @desi What if last name was O'Brian  ... wouldn't you want the keep the quote ?

Comment: @desi  on second thought.  If you REALLY want to remove the quotes and commas from the final results  ...  ,Value = replace(replace(stuff(B.RetVal,1,charindex('=',B.RetVal+'='),''),',',''),'''','') ..

Comment: @desi This dbFiddle illustrates my last comment  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=a220eeb8d9dde1e31db56886160764f3

Comment: I use replace function and it works good as suggested for me in my scenario.
Thank you a Ton,  it really helped me so much.  I appreciate your instant help to resolve this problem.!